# How do you assign a non string value (enum/class) to application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm using AWS in my project and I just want to make `Regions` configurable in properties file.

So `com.amazonaws.regions.Regions` accepts enum values like `Regions.AP_EAST_1`.

I tried assigning it in `application.properties`:

```
aws.s3.config.region=com.amazonaws.regions.Regions.US_WEST_2
```

```
@Value("${aws.s3.config.region}")
private Regions clientRegion;
```

This just doesn't work out. It gives me this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Regions]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 2):

Spring knows how to map enums. Just use the enum value (not a fully-qualified name):

```
aws.s3.config.region: US_WEST_2
```

Note also that [Spring Cloud AWS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) is available (though it may not always be the best choice; it has very strong opinions), and that in general it's better to use `@ConfigurationProperties` or at a minimum constructor injection instead of `@Value` on a field, which has all the pitfalls of field injection.